# Javascript RegEx string

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

I have a string, suppose it is - `"abc, Ext- 2345; pqr, Ext- 1445, xyz, Ext- 1234 "`

I want to delete `"pqr, Ext- 1445"` but I know only pqr beforehand. So, I have a regex formula so that I can provide "pqr", and it'll delete `"pqr, Ext- 1445"` so mb pqr and after that 11 char after pqr.. How to write the regex, formula??

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one of these?

You could have tried yourself using https://regex101.com/

```js
console.log(
  "abc, Ext- 2345; pqr, Ext- 1445, xyz, Ext- 1234 ".replace(/pqr.{13}/,"")
)

console.log(
  "abc, Ext- 2345; pqr, Ext- 1445, xyz, Ext- 1234 ".replace(/pqr,.*?, /,"")
)
```